# Issue in running foreground service for fetching location

Tags: notifications, foreground-service, android-8.1-oreo

I am running foreground service in oreo. Its working in API 26 but I am getting crash in API 27 I tried all the possible solutions but cant able to resolve this issue.

The following is the code of my service which I used to fetch location

```
public class LocationMonitoringService extends Service implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = LocationMonitoringService.class.getSimpleName();
    GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();


    public static final String ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAST = LocationMonitoringService.class.getName() + "LocationBroadcast";
    public static final String EXTRA_LATITUDE = "extra_latitude";
    public static final String EXTRA_LONGITUDE = "extra_longitude";

    private static final String ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID = "4973297852329223684";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 282929;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText("SmartTracker Running")
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            Notification notification = builder.build();
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }

        mLocationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000*10);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000*10);


        int priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY; //by default
        //PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY, PRIORITY_LOW_POWER, PRIORITY_NO_POWER are the other priority modes


        mLocationRequest.setPriority(priority);
        mLocationClient.connect();

        //Make it stick to the notification panel so it is less prone to get cancelled by the Operating System.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * LOCATION CALLBACKS
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

            Log.d(TAG, "== Error On onConnected() Permission not granted");
            //Permission not granted by user so cancel the further execution.

            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        Log.d(TAG, "Connected to Google API");
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
     * location client drops because of an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    }

    //to get the location change
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Location changed");

        if (location != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())+" "+String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
            //Send result to activities
            //sendMessageToUI(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
        }
    }

    private void sendMessageToUI(String lat, String lng) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Sending info...");

        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LATITUDE, lat);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LONGITUDE, lng);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to connect to Google API");

    }
```

My activity code from where I call the service

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationMonitoringService.class);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForegroundService(intent);

    }else {
        startService(intent);
    }
```

the app craches on opening it the error log when crash occurs

```
2019-03-11 12:17:58.707 32102-32102/com.example.backgroundlocation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.backgroundlocation, PID: 32102
    android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=4973297852329223684 pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x50 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1818)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```